# .NET Google Action WebHook Fulfillment RegisterUpdate Intent

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, asp.net-webhooks

I am building a WebHook for Google actions - Dialogflow Intent Fulfillment.

At the beginning I was developing the WebHook on node.js but since Google block external API calls for the free plan I decided to switch to .NET WebHook (since this is a test project for some students we are not going to get a purchased plan). Easily the WebHook is calling some API of us.

The problem I am dealing with right now is a feature we implemented in the node.js original version, I am talking about the RegisterUpdate Intent that registers Daily updates.

I am wondering if it is possible to deal with this feature also if my WebHook is in c#. If so, How?

[This](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/daily) are some of the official docs talking about this feature.

Currently we are developing the WebHook following [this](https://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2018/09/24/dialogflow-fulfillment-with-c-and-app-engine/) easy logic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a technical perspective it is possible and not so hard, since everything in node.js just creates a JSON object what we have to do is create the same object as response and [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/daily#json) it says how.